# Multiple versions of clang with openmp

Tags: clang

On Ubuntu 22.04 (and previous versions as well) it is possible to have multiple clang versions installed at once. However, OpenMP needs to be installed separately for each clang version (for example `sudo apt install libomp-12-dev` for clang-12). Installation of a particular openmp version uninstalls other versions. libomp-X-dev is produces linker error with clang-Y (when X != Y).

Is it possible to have multiple versions of openmp installed at once?

(It would be fine to have a single version of openmp that works with all clang version)